# MongoDB update queries: when updating a document, is it better to filter documents that haven't been updated?

Tags: mongodb

How smart is MongoDB about updating documents, will it know to not bother 'updating' a document if it wouldn't actually change anything?

Compare the following two update queries:

```
db.test.update({}, {'$set': {'something': true}})
db.test.update({'something': {'$ne': true}}, {'$set': {'something': true}})
```

The intention is to set the `something` property of all the documents in the `test` collection to `true`.

Assume some of the documents may already have the `something` property set to `true`.

Let's not consider indexes, as I think that's besides the point.

Answer (score 3):

I think it doesn't make a big difference, since MongoDB has to walk all documents anyway (because we're not using indexes).

Also, an update is a three step operation:

1. Fetch a page with the document from disk to RAM (if not already there)
2. Update in-memory
3. Flush dirty page to disk

The first part happens anyway. Now, if we have a check at second step, it burns a little more CPU, but it is countered with a potentially decreased number of dirty pages. My gut feeling is that your first line doesn't do checks and updates all documents.

I hope that core 10gen guys will show up in this topic and tell us exactly what's happening.